# python 2.7 socket communication with json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sockets

I want to send/recv data through socket.

I use python 2.7 because of ROS(melodic) and also use python 3.6 because of tensorflow.

The dict data, for example `{'key_name':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}`, is sent and encoded with `JSONEncoder.encoder()`.
The Client received the json data with `loads()` and resend it to the Server.
The Client uses python 2.7 and the Server uses python 3.6

```
def _send(socket, send_data):
    json_data = json.JSONEncoder().encode(send_data)
    socket.sendall(json_data)

def _recv(socket):
    recv_data = socket.recv(BUFSIZE)
    json_data = json.loads(recv_data, encoding="utf-8")

    return json_data
```

I have the error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/deoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 4097 (char 4096)
```

I need a python code which runs on both python 2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: How do you know the response is only 4096 bytes?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006696/python-2-7-socket-communication-with-json seems to confirm what @user207421 is suggesting. You should chech your json output, and make sure you arn't cutting any data off because BUFSIZE is too small.

Answer (score 3):

The error is coming from json decoder.

```
json_data = json.loads(recv_data, encoding="utf-8"),
```

It is expected when your json data ( in your case the `recv_data`) is not in proper format. Usually missing a comma ',' or something.
For debugging I would suggest you to dump the data received at server, before going for `json.loads()`

Comment: You are right with what you are saying.  I'm thinking it may not be malformed json, but instead `BUFSIZE` isn't big enough.

Comment: @Simon Yeah right. Dumping the output is the way to confirm

Comment: I tired your answer already but it didn't work for me.  
So I changed library msgpack. It looks good to me. Thank you